# How to insert characters with special meaning into a document

Tags: symbols, pdftex

I was trying to add the symbol ^ in the document and getting error. How could I do that

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\^
\end{document}
```

I need to add \,$... to document

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you write `\^`, then tex assumes you’re trying to write a circumflex on top of something and looks for that something.  The first thing it finds in your code is the `\end` of `\end{document}`, in which case, it doesn’t find an `\end{document}` command (just `{document}`).

You can get around this by giving `\^` a “null” argument: `\^{}`.  Or, more cumbersomely, you can write `\textasciicircum`, for a full-size circumflex (in T1, at least).

Different packages offer variants.  For instance, the `\upp` of `wsuipa` is a little more pointed, from memory.

Comment: This is incorrect. `\end` is a single token which would be the argument of `\^` in this case.

Comment: `\textasciicircum` and `\^{}` are not the same character (given suitable font encoding such as `T1`) one is a small raised accent character over a null base, The other is (should be) the full sized ascii character

Comment: @DavidCarlisle.  Thanks very much for those corrections.  I’ve worked them into the answer.

Answer (score 8):

depending what you want to do

```
\verb|^|   \verb|\|
```

or

```
 \textasciicircum
 \textasciibackslash
 \$
```

Note `\textasciibackslash` works better after `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as the default `OT1` encoded fonts do not have this character (except `tt`) so the character is taken from the math fonts in that case).

Answer (score 3):

You can insert most of the symbols by escaping them with the `\`:
`\$`, `\&`, `\%`, etc.
Some have special instructions: `\textbackslash` for the backslash.

Are you sure you need the ^? Maybe the `\wedge` is more suitable.

For more symbols, have a look at [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

The "circumflex" accent, `^`, is generally meant to be placed above some other character, e.g., `e` or `E`. If you want to display it by itself, you must add something like a "null" (empty) group:

```
\^{}, \^\null
```

On methods for displaying some of TeX's other "special-meaning" symbols, see, e.g., Table 1 of the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world
$\wedge$,  \textbackslash\, \$
\end{document}
```

[image]