# How to display the character ^ in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert characters with special meaning into a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66631/how-to-insert-characters-with-special-meaning-into-a-document)

I have tried `\^`  but that doesn't work.

I need to display something like this text:

```
(^OnDocumentDidLoad)
```

Comment: Have you tried `\^{}`?

Comment: @brainray Does the suggested linked question help? If so, this question is likely to be closed as a duplicate: we aim to have one 'definitive' place for answers for each question.

Comment: @brainray Use the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) or Detexify (http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) where you can find all(?) special symbols in LaTeX.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\textasciicircum` in textmode.